# How do you export a region in paper.js

Tags: svg, paperjs, bounds

I'm currently using the following code to export a region on a layer using paper.js:

```
var boundsArtboard = new Rectangle({x:10,y:10, width:100, height:100});
var svg = paper.project.exportSVG({asString:true,precision: 5, bounds:boundsArtboard});
```

When I view the exported SVG in a web browser it appears correctly. However, if I open this SVG file in Illustrator, the SVG file contains all objects that exist on that currently layer. See attached SVG image example. How do I just export the objects in the bounds and not everything on the layer?

[Example SVG export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAcFA.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new temp layer
- Loop all objects and check if they intersect or contain segments inside boundsArtboard rectangle
- If they do, clone path and add it to tempLayer
- Export tempLayer
- Delete tempLayer